# Модальное окно по клику на button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопка отправки формы button. По клику на нее в конце должно появляться модальное окно. Вместо этого, окно появляется, сразу идет перезагрузка страницы и окно исчезает. я так понимаю, это именно из-за того, что это button. Какой выход может быть?

проблема именно когда button находится в теге form. Причем не важно, где наше модальное окно, в форме или нет. Все равно окно открывается и сразу закрывается

```
$("#sub_toggle").click(function() {
    $('#sub_modal').show();
});

<div id="sub_modal"></div>
<button id="sub_toggle"></button>
```

Comment: покажите html код

Comment: поправил первый пост

Comment: форма еще не даже не подключена

Answer (score 1):

**Можно сделать так:**

```js
$("#sub_toggle").click(function() {
  $('#sub_modal').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#sub_modal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="sub_modal">модалка</div>
<button id="sub_toggle">кнопка</button>
```

**Но:**

Страница перезагружается из-за того, что форма отправляться. Если форма на ajax то делать проверку отправки формы через jquery ajax success, а если нет, то можете отправить параметр  в url через `php` типо `index.php?response="openmodal"` а потом делать проверку типа `if $_GET['respons'] == 'openmodal'`

Comment: чем это отличается от моего скрипта ?) хоть toggle, хоть slideToggle эффект один и тот же

Comment: <button id="sub_toggle"">  лишняя кавычка у вас тут

Comment: этот тут я ошибся, в разметки все нормально(

Comment: проблема именно когда button находится в теге form. Причем не важно, где наше модальное окно, в форме или нет. Все равно окно открывается и сразу закрывается

Comment: как тогда лучше вывести это окно после отправки формы ?

Comment: @Даниил  согласен с Вами.

Comment: понял, спасибо, так и сделаю

Comment: @Даниил  да, добавил в ответ

Comment: Конструкция типа $('form').submit(function(){event.preventDefault();}); не даст перезагрузить страницу. Или я что-то не понял?

Comment: @Devergence верно, но автору скорее всего нужно сделать вывод с ответом, event добавьте в скобки

Comment: Проблема в том, что отправляется форма и страница перезагружается. Как решить проблему правильным способом я написал ниже в своем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

У тега `<button>` есть атрибут `type`

По умолчанию он установлен как `type="submit"`

Чтобы форма не отправлялась достаточно установить `type="button"`, что даст понять броузеру, что это кнопка-заглушка - [подробности о теге `<button>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button)

Comment: Тоже что и event.preventDefault();

Comment: Логично предположить, что если там стоит button submit, то мне нужно чтобы форма отправлялась. Иначе я бы мог использовать любой тег

Comment: @DenisDenis, так нужно было оставить значение по умолчанию на кнопке, которая отправляет форму. На всех остальных -> нужно было поставить `type="button"`

Comment: @Даниил, не то же самое как бы... одно дело использовать нативный html5 и сделать все семантически верно, другое -- использовать JS там, где это не нужно. С таким успехом можно вообще не использовать форму, и даже инпуты, а написать все через '`<div editable="true">`'. Костыльно, неудобно, бесполезно.

Comment: Если есть js можно и без этого

Comment: @Даниил, сециально для вас я написал вот это: **С таким успехом можно вообще не использовать форму, и даже инпуты, а написать все через '<div editable="true">'. Костыльно, неудобно, бесполезно.** Просто, очевидно, что добавить аттрибут, это гораздо проще, чем вешать обработчик кликов, тем более через jQ, и тем более явно, а не через деллегирование.

Comment: а, что значить для всех остальных ? есть одна кнопка, после отправки формы должно появится модальное окно. Я просто не подумал, что форма отправляется и идет перезагрузка страницы